# TFS Code Review Distribution List?

Tags: tfs

We are using TFS for code management.  When I want to send something for a code review, I have to select the different reviewers on our team one at a time.

Is there a way to make a "distribution list" on TFS?  Something I could just say "Corporate Code Reviewers" or something and submit to all of them?

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/process-templates/define-groups-teams-permissions-plug-in